# Layer list button selector does not fill width

Tags: android, android-button

**EDIT:** It seems that the layer list is drawing like so: The normal button background 9-patch is at the back.  The highlight 9-patch is being drawn *inside* the normal background, instead of on top of it.  So, its going inside the padding box specified in the 9-patch properties of the normal background.  This was revealed when I tinkered with the padding box on the normal background.  This is not what I want.  Is there another way, without using a layer list, for me to simply layer the highlight image over top of the normal background in the pressed state?

I have a selector for a button background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btnprimary" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_primary_pressed_bg" android:state_pressed="true" />

</selector>
```

`btnprimary` is a 9-patch .png file which is the normal state.  `btn_primary_pressed_bg` is a layer list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btnprimary"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btnhighlight"/>

</layer-list>
```

As you can see, the pressed state is the normal background with a highlight layered on top to indicate the pressed state.  `btnhighlight` is another 9-patch .png which has exactly the same  stretchable area and padding box as the non-pressed state background.

This works *almost* perfectly.  The problem is that in the pressed state, the standard background shows up normally as it should, but the highlight over top does not completely fill the width of the button (the height is filled normally).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Pressed]

And here's the same button in its normal (not-pressed) state:

[image: Not pressed]

Interestingly enough, if I replace the layer-list in the selector with just the highlight on its own for the pressed state, it fills the width exactly:

[image: Highlighted]

This pattern applies to all the buttons in the app.  I do not have any padding specified for the button.

**EDIT:** Here's the result of the suggestion provided by slukian:

[image: Strange]

Comment: are you sure that your `btnhighlight` png doesn't have some empty space on the right and left of the dark blue rectangle?

Comment: Yes - you can see in the third screenshot what the background looks like if I'm using only `btnhighlight` instead of the layer list.